# How to add OAuth 2.0 to my Spring project?

Tags: java, spring

I've started my project with [this](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest/) Spring tutorial. Now I want to develop it, the first step is to add OAuth 2.0 to this project, but when I was looking for some tutorial on how to add it is always started with "Create Your Java Application with Spring, add dependencies: Spring Web,
Spring Security...".

Is there any way to add these dependencies to the existing project? Or any better way to develop existing projects?

**Or should I build it again?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this dependency in your `pom.xml` under dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Further it depends upon your requirements like if you want your resource server or not.